# guía sobre programación de un dispositivo ble ibeacon en Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, bluetooth

Hola eh estado buscando mucho documentación para detectar dispositivos ble desde una pantalla de mi aplicación con Android studio aun así todo lo que eh intentado no ah dado resultados simplemente no encuentra ningún dispositivo, alguien sabe de algún foro o algo que me explique de mejor manera el como hacerlo, solo necesito que cuando la app detecte el beacon reciba una notificación de que esta dentro del área
Este es el dispositivo que quiero detectar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

adjunto lo que tengo, pero al momento de scannear los dispositivos bluetooth no encuentra nada solo muestra el toast de no s eecontro ningún beacon

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.altbeacon.beacon.Beacon;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconConsumer;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconParser;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Identifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.RangeNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Region;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;


public class TiendasCercanas extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener, BeaconConsumer,
        RangeNotifier {

    protected final String TAG = 
TiendasCercanas.this.getClass().getSimpleName();;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 1;
    private static final long DEFAULT_SCAN_PERIOD_MS = 6000l;
    private static final String ALL_BEACONS_REGION = 
"AllBeaconsRegion";

    // Para interactuar con los beacons desde una actividad
    private BeaconManager mBeaconManager;

    // Representa el criterio de campos con los que buscar beacons
    private Region mRegion;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tiendas_cercanas);

        getStartButton().setOnClickListener(this);
        getStopButton().setOnClickListener(this);

        mBeaconManager = 
BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

        // Fijar un protocolo beacon, Eddystone en este caso
        mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));

    ArrayList<Identifier> identifiers = new ArrayList<>();

    mRegion = new Region(ALL_BEACONS_REGION, identifiers);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if (view.equals(findViewById(R.id.startReadingBeaconsButton))) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            // Si los permisos de localización todavía no se han concedido, solicitarlos
            if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                askForLocationPermissions();

            } else { // Permisos de localización concedidos

                prepareDetection();
            }

        } else { // Versiones de Android < 6

            prepareDetection();
        }

    } else if (view.equals(findViewById(R.id.stopReadingBeaconsButton))) {

        stopDetectingBeacons();

        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // Desactivar bluetooth
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
        }
    }
}


private void prepareDetection() {

    if (!isLocationEnabled()) {

        askToTurnOnLocation();

    } else { // Localización activada, comprobemos el bluetooth

        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {

            showToastMessage("Este dispositivo no soporta bluetooth, no es posible buscar beacons");

        } else if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {

            startDetectingBeacons();

        } else {

            // Pedir al usuario que active el bluetooth
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH) {

        // Usuario ha activado el bluetooth
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            startDetectingBeacons();

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) { // User refuses to enable bluetooth

            showToastMessage("Con el bluetooth desactivado no es posible buscar beacons");
        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}


private void startDetectingBeacons() {

    // Fijar un periodo de escaneo
    mBeaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(DEFAULT_SCAN_PERIOD_MS);

    mBeaconManager.bind(this);

    // Desactivar botón de comenzar
    getStartButton().setEnabled(false);
    getStartButton().setAlpha(.5f);

    // Activar botón de parar
    getStopButton().setEnabled(true);
    getStopButton().setAlpha(1);
}

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {

    try {
        // Empezar a buscar los beacons que encajen con el el objeto Región pasado, incluyendo
        // actualizaciones en la distancia estimada
        mBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(mRegion);

        showToastMessage("comenzar busqueda");

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Se ha producido una excepción al empezar a buscar beacons " + e.getMessage());
    }

    mBeaconManager.addRangeNotifier(this);
}


@Override
public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {

    if (beacons.size() == 0) {
        showToastMessage("no se encontro ningún beacon");
    }

    for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
        showToastMessage(getString(R.string.beacon_detected, beacon.getId3()));
    }
}

private void stopDetectingBeacons() {

    try {
        mBeaconManager.stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(mRegion);
        showToastMessage("Detener busqueda");
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Se ha producido una excepción al parar de buscar beacons " + e.getMessage());
    }

    mBeaconManager.removeAllRangeNotifiers();

    // Desenlazar servicio de beacons
    mBeaconManager.unbind(this);

    // Activar botón de comenzar
    getStartButton().setEnabled(true);
    getStartButton().setAlpha(1);

    // Desactivar botón de parar
    getStopButton().setEnabled(false);
    getStopButton().setAlpha(.5f);
}


private void askForLocationPermissions() {

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("se reuieren permisos de ubicacion");
    builder.setMessage("Dar permisos de Ubicacion");
    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
    builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                prepareDetection();
            } else {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Activar Ubicacion");
                builder.setMessage("Ubicacion no activada, imposible buscar beacons");
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {

                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}


private boolean isLocationEnabled() {

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    boolean networkLocationEnabled = false;

    boolean gpsLocationEnabled = false;

    try {
        networkLocationEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        gpsLocationEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Excepción al obtener información de localización");
    }

    return networkLocationEnabled || gpsLocationEnabled;
}


private void askToTurnOnLocation() {

    // Notificar al usuario
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Ubicacion desactivada");
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Abrir ajustes de ubición", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}

private Button getStartButton() {
    return (Button) findViewById(R.id.startReadingBeaconsButton);
}

private Button getStopButton() {
    return (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopReadingBeaconsButton);
}


private void showToastMessage (String message) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, message, 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mBeaconManager.removeAllRangeNotifiers();
        mBeaconManager.unbind(this);
    }
}
```

y este es mi layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".TiendasCercanas">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startReadingBeaconsButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:text="@string/start_button_text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/stopReadingBeaconsButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="@string/stop_button_text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Cuales son tus errores, lo que haz intentado, tus pruebas? que haz programado hasta ahora.. debes colocar un ejemplo para que tu pregunta no sea tomada como de "opinión"

Comment: Como es eso de que "no inicia y tampoco muestra errores" :|  no inicia y no muestra ningún mensaje en el LogCat? Te sugerimos revisar [ask], edita tu pregunta por favor, saludos.

Comment: disculpen, me refería que al momento de iniciarlo y presionar el botón para escanear el beacon no muestra nada como si el beacon estuviera apagado pero no lo esta con el ligthblue lo veo e incluso puedo conectarme